Jmeter HTTP Request Sampler Return Unrecognized IPV6 Address format
I had created a project using Jmeter and created thread group and one Http Request sampler.
I left the server name or ip empty and put the url in path section but when i generate report using this command
 jmeter.sh -g Report.jtl -o report

It shows

Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException/Non HTTP response message: Unrecognized IPv6 address format.

What could be the problem?

I cannot reproduce your issue with latest JMeter 5.6.3 so I think it's some form of a bug which has been fixed.
In general it's recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading, you can always get a stable version of JMeter from Downloads page.
